# How to create MySQL database for "type" quiz

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I am new to HTML/PHP/JavaScript/MySQL. I have a quiz written in JS & HTML, but I think I need a database of all questions & answers. I am  using PHPmyAdmin to create the database & tables.

My quiz is a type quiz, kind of like a "What type of ____ are you?" (ex. color, dog, personality) therefore, there is no 1 true correct answer to any of my questions.

I am unsure what to include in my database for this quiz in order for it to run. 
I will include a skeleton of my code, if that will help you. I do apologize if this seems vague.

JavaScript

```
<head>
<title>Questions</title>
<script language="Javascript">

function process()
{
var Ans1 = 0;
var Ans3 = 0;
var Ans4 = 0;
var Ans2 = 0;

var f = document.f;
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < f.q1.length; i++) if (f.q1[i].checked) value = f.q1[i].value;
    if (value == "1") { Ans3++; } <!--put in order with least likely answer first-->
    if (value == "2") { Ans4++; }
    if (value == "3") { Ans2++; }
    if (value == "4") { Ans1++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.q2.length; i++) if (f.q2[i].checked) value = f.q2[i].value;
    if (value == "1") { Ans3++; } <!--put in order with least likely answer first-->
    if (value == "2") { Ans4++; }
    if (value == "3") { Ans2++; }
    if (value == "4") { Ans1++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.q3.length; i++) if (f.q3[i].checked) value = f.q3[i].value;
    if (value == "1") { Ans3++; } <!--put in order with least likely answer first-->
    if (value == "2") { Ans4++; }
    if (value == "3") { Ans2++; }
    if (value == "4") { Ans1++; }

<!--Copy the above for loop for all subsequent questions, if needed-->

var out = "Ans1"; )<!--default value, Ans1-->
i = Ans1;

if (Ans4 > i) { out ="Ans4"; i = Ans4; } <!--ex. out = "Ans4"; i="Result4";-->
if (Ans3 > i) { out ="Ans3"; i = Ans3; }
if (Ans2 > i) { out ="Ans2"; i = Ans2; } <!--ex. out = "Ans3"; i="Result2";-->
location.href = out + ".shtml"; <!--I believe this should display results page, based on your computed result -->
}

function err(msg, url, line)
{
location.href = "error.html";
}

//window.onerror = err;
// -->
</script>
</head>
```

HTML Quiz Question/Answer Options

```
<body>
<?php include ('SiteMenu'); ?>
Answer the questions below...

<form name="f">

<b>What is your answer to question #1?<br></b>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="4">Ans1.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">Ans3.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2">Ans4.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3">Ans2.<br><br>

<b>What is your answer to question #2?<br></b>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2">Ans4.<br>       
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="4">Ans1.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1">Ans3.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3">Ans2.<br><br>

<b>What is your answer to question #3?<br></b>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="4">Ans1.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">Ans3.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="2">Ans4.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="3">Ans2.<br><br>

<!--Input more questions, if needed, here-->

Thank you for taking our quiz! <br>
<input type="button" value="Find my Result!" onclick="process();"><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
Ok. I am sorry, just trying to better understand how to input the table. This is what I am thinking you mean?
I have 2 tables in my database: questions & answers
In the questions table it looks like:

```
qID      aID      qText
q1                What is your favorite color?
q2                This is the second question
```

and so on

Then, my answers table looks like

```
qID      valID      aText
q1                  Green
q1                  Blue
q1                  Red
q2                  question 2 answer choice1
q2                  question 2 answer choice2
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Basically you want

```
Questions, ID and Text
Choices ID, QuestionID and the text
```

Answers is just

```
QuestionID, ChoiceID


Questions Table
Id Text 
1  'What is your favourite colour?'

Choices Table
Id, QuestionID, Text
1   1           'Red'
2   1           'Blue'
3   1           'Green'
4   1           'Pale Blue Green with yellow dots'

Answers
VictimID QuestionID ChoiceID
(userID?)1          4
```

Comment: Would I only need 2 tables within the database? One for questions, another for answers?
In the Questions table: have the question ID (q1,q2,...) & text (actual questions)
Then in the Answers table: question ID (q1,q2,...) again & choiceID (the value of their answer)?
Is that what you mean?

Comment: No Questions is 1, 'What is your favourite Colour, Choices is 1,1,'Mange' 1,2, Puce etc Answers is 1,2 if your victim chose puce.

Comment: Your second table is not answers, it's choices. Answers is the one your victim chose.

Comment: Please see my edit of the original post (I posted an UPDATE) to see if I understand what you mean

Comment: Oh, I see your edit now, I will work on revising mine!